# Hibernate / SQL Server and trying to use newsequentialid

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Good Morning,

I have a table in SQL Server which uses newsequentialid() as its default for the primary key. Pre-Hibernate it worked great in keeping the keys sequential but I can't seem to find any configuration settings for Hibernate which allow me to keep using it.

I did come across a neat solution which involves implementing IdentifierGenerator to fetch the next sequential key, (which is done through a stored procedure), and then setting up the key on my table like so:

```html
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "com.test.test.helpers.PrimaryKeyGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name="MyID", columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier", nullable=false, unique=true)
private String MyID;
```

However, the downside to this is it now executes an extra select every time I persist a new object. I am also using a connection pool which I confirmed I can't autowire into that class so I'm missing out on that benefit as well.

Let me know what you think and to be honest I am quite new to SQL Server and even newer to Hibernate so yes, I could very easily be missing the obvious :)

Thanks!